# <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for login() - Angular TestBed

Tags: angular, typescript, testbed

I am trying to write a unit test for one of the components named Login.Component.ts whose code is given below. I tried various approaches but unable to get a successful response. Before explaining the component and service code, I want to know –

1. `TestBed` – My understanding was that testbed in angular initiates and setup all the boilerplate code (required for testing like creating view, initializing and injecting service, creating routers and all this only for testing environment) by itself and all we need to do is to write some minimal code like below –

   ```
   beforeEach(() => {
         TestBed.configureTestingModule({
             imports:[RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])],
     declarations: [LoginComponent],
     providers: [AuthenticationService]
   })
     .compileComponents();


   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   authenticationservice = TestBed.get(AuthenticationService);
   ```

   });

But looks like my understanding is wrong as component and authenticationservice doesn’t look like the objects as seems from the error I am getting –

```
<spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for login() - Angular TestBed
```

Login.Component.ts -

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html'
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private router: Router
      ) { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      login({ formValue }: { formValue: LoginRequest }) {
        this.authenticationService.login(formValue.user, formValue.password)
          .subscribe(
          res => {
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
          },
          error => {
            Console.log(“Login Error”);
          });
      }
    }
```

Authentication.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  login(user: string, pass: string): Observable<authToken> {
    return this.httpClient.post<authToken >(SomeURI+'/oauth/token', {},
      {
        params: new HttpParams()
          .set('username', userId)
          .set('password', password)
      }
    ).do(this.htoken);
  }

private htoken(token: authToken) {
    //some local storage logic here
  }
```

approutes.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
30.   { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [IsAuthenticatedActivateGuard]  },

      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},

      { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent, canActivate: [IsAuthenticatedActivateGuard] }
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(
          appRoutes
        )
      ],
      exports: [
        RouterModule
      ]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Writing Test** -

**Approach 1** -

```
//imports

fdescribe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let authenticationservice: AuthenticationService;
  let router: Router;
  let spyService: any;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;

  interface LoginRequest {
    user: string;
    password: string;
  }

  let creds: LoginRequest = {
    user: "username",
    password: "userpasswd"
  }

  let m: MenuConfig = {
  }
  let oToken: OauthToken = {
    access_token: "abc",
    token_type: "jj",
    refresh_token: "y",
    expires_in: 10,
    scope: "g",
    acessibleMenuItems: m
  };


  beforeEach(() => {
    component = new LoginComponent(authenticationservice, router, null);
    authenticationservice = new AuthenticationService(httpClient);
  });


  fit('should login successfully', () => {
    spyService = spyOn(authenticationservice, 'login').and.callFake(() => {
      return Observable.of(oToken);
    });
    component.login({ value: creds });
    expect(spyService).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  })
});
```

**Error** -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
```

**Approach 2** – When I thought of using TestBed assuming that it will take care of everything,

```
//imports

describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
  let authenticationservice: AuthenticationService;
  let router: Router;
  let spyService: any;
  let spyRouter: any;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;

  interface LoginRequest {
    user: string;
    password: string;
  }

  let creds: LoginRequest = {
    user: "username",
    password: "userpasswd"
  }

  let m: MenuConfig = {
  }
  let oToken: OauthToken = {
    access_token: "abc",
    token_type: "jj",
    refresh_token: "y",
    expires_in: 10,
    scope: "g",
    acessibleMenuItems: m
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports:[RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])],
      declarations: [LoginComponent],
      providers: [AuthenticationService]
    })
      .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    authenticationservice = TestBed.get(AuthenticationService);

    //fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should login successfully', () => {
    spyService = spyOn(authenticationservice, 'login').and.callFake(() => {
      return Observable.of(oToken);
    });
    //spyRouter = spyOn((<any>component).router, 'navigate').and.callThrough();
    component.login({ value: creds });
    expect(spyService).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    //expect(spyRouter).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  })
});
```

**Error** -

```
Error: Template parse errors:
'app-messages' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-messages' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-messages' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<h4>Login</h4>
<hr>
[ERROR ->]<app-messages></app-messages>
<!-- Really good forms resource: https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/LoginComponent.html@2:0
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("nputs 'name' attribute -->
<form name="form" class="form-horizontal" novalidateautocomplete="false" [ERROR ->]#f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="login(f)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="user-input">User Id</la"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/LoginComponent.html@6:73
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="user-input" placeholder="User Id" ngModel name="user" [ERROR ->]#user="ngModel" required>
    <app-input-validation-messages [model]="user"></app-input-validation-me"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/LoginComponent.html@9:102
Can't bind to 'model' since it isn't a known property of 'app-input-validation-messages'.
1. If 'app-input-validation-messages' is an Angular component and it has 'model' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-input-validation-messages' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("ceholder="User Id" ngModel name="user" #user="ngModel" required>
    <app-input-validation-messages [ERROR ->][model]="user"></app-input-validation-messages>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/LoginComponent.html@10:35
'app-input-validation-messages' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-input-validation-messages' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-input-validation-messages' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("type="text" id="user-input" placeholder="User Id" ngModel name="user" #user="ngModel" required>
    [ERROR ->]<app-input-validation-messages [model]="user"></app-input-validation-messages>
```

**And**

```
Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for login()
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
    at SpyRegistry.spyOn (http://localhost:9877/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?da99c5b057693d025fad3d7685e1590600ca376d:4364:15)
    at Env.spyOn (http://localhost:9877/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?da99c5b057693d025fad3d7685e1590600ca376d:925:32)
    at spyOn (http://localhost:9877/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?da99c5b057693d025fad3d7685e1590600ca376d:4203:18)
```

No idea what am I doing wrong here. Have I messed it up?

**Approach 3** - Somehow seems to be working, not sure what I did different. Yet, I am unable to figure out as how to test the error path of the component here in second test below i.e. asserting for some error message or something.

```
describe('LoginComponent', () => {

  let component: any;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
  let authenticationservice: any;
  let router: Router;
  let spyService: any;
  let spyRouter: any;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;

  interface LoginRequest {
    user: string;
    password: string;
  }


  let creds: LoginRequest = {
    user: "username",
    password: "userpasswd"
  }

  let m: Config = {
  }
  let oToken: authToken = {
    access_token: "abc",
    token_type: "jj",
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        SharedModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        LoginComponent
      ],      
      providers: [           
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    authenticationservice = TestBed.get(AuthenticationService);
  });








  it('should login successfully', () => {
    spyService = spyOn(authenticationservice, 'login').and.callFake(() => {
      return Observable.of(oToken);
    });
    spyRouter = spyOn((<any>component).router, 'navigate');//.and.callThrough();
    component.login({ value: creds });
    expect(spyService).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(spyRouter).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('should throw error message - bad credentials', () => {

    spyService = spyOn(authenticationservice, 'login').and.returnValue(Observable.throw("Could not log in: Bad credentials"));
    spyRouter = spyOn((<any>component).router, 'navigate');
    var out = component.login({ value: creds });
    console.log(":::::::"+out);
    //how to put an assertion for Login Error Message here assuming that is returned by the catch block.
    expect(spyService).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  })
});
```

Comment: AuthenticationService seems to be not a mock.

Comment: @mrkernelpanic, what does that mean? I believe using spyOn, one can mock any method for any service or component etc. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes you can spy anything. But you have to import every dependency of your service into your testbed. If the dependencies have dependencies, you also have to import them, etc. That's why you mock your dependencies.

Comment: @apun did you try getting your service instance via the injector ? Using the testbed can sometimes lead to errors like that. Use `fixture.debugElement.injector.get(AuthenticationService)` and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 2):

According to **[the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-a-dependency)** :

> You may also be able to get the service from the root injector via `TestBed.get()`. This is easier to remember and less verbose. But it only works when Angular injects the component with the service instance in the test's root injector.

So maybe you should try using the injector :

> The safest way to get the injected service, the way that always works, is to get it from the injector of the component-under-test. The component injector is a property of the fixture's DebugElement.

```
authenticationservice = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(AuthenticationService)
```

**EDIT** Try injecting the dependency directly into your test

```
it('should login successfully', inject([AuthenticationService], (service: AuthenticationService) => {...}));
```

Comment: Sure..trying it...meanwhile please take a look at my edit.

Comment: You need to import `RouterTestingModule` into your test bed, to avoid the real routing. It's in `@angular/router/testing`.

Comment: I was following http://plnkr.co/edit/jqw3ddMQU7zPQg9KBXJE?p=preview , still wondering how come services work for him the same way along with spyOn. Its from https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/angular-test-bed/.  Thanks for the pointer on RouterTestingModule . Appreciate your help. But wondering the issue with service yet.

Comment: Is it normal that you removed `fixture.detectChanges()` into the `beforeEach` ? Put it back, see if it works.

Comment: Is it possible to email you all these details if that helps? Feeling awkward for putting in so many comments and bothering you here : (

Comment: You don't need to e-mail me the details, simply edit your question and notice me when it's done. I'll check for errors and let you know what I've found.

Comment: I have updated all the details...hope it will be more clear from end now.

Comment: Sorry I'm home now but I will look at it tomorrow. As for your second approach, try uncommenting fixture.detectChanges, and declare MessagesComponent in your testbed (and mock it if you want). But you understood it well, testbed is kind of for the boilerplate code, it allows you to test a component inside angular's context. As for your first approach, this is an isolated test, that you don't bond to angular. It works well too, it's really up to you to decide which approach you want. The error for the first test is that you need to mock your router : `router = {navigate: () => null};`

Comment: thank you so much for taking out time to assist me on this one. I did uncomment fixture.detectChanges but no luck. I understand the first approach but kind of lost one on second one but want to follow the second one as test bed seems more of an angular approach. thanks for the pointer on router in the first approach. will try this one as well.

Comment: could you please let me as how and where to put `router = {navigate: () => null};`. As its a part of component, so a bit confused as how to spy/mock it using jasmine i.e. first approach. BTW, looks like I got the second approach working somehow, not sure what different i did this time. Posting it here, please take a look and provide your much valuable comments.

Comment: Well in your case, the easiest way to mock it is to just spy it in a `beforeEach` : `spyOn(router, 'navigate').and.callFake(() => null);`. be sure to mock it **once you have fetched it** (with the injector or the testbed), otherwise you will have the same error as previously.